# Find isomorphic vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with $V = S \bigoplus B$ and $W = S \bigoplus D$ but $B \ncong D$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm having some trouble with this. It seems very difficult to construct the spaces in such a way that $ V = S \bigoplus B$ and $W = S \bigoplus D$ with the conditions that $ B \ncong D$.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: A vector space over a given field is determined up to isomorphism class by the cardinality of its dimension. Look below for a second hint:

> In cardinal arithmetic, $\aleph_0 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.

And the solution is:

> Take $S$ to be of countably infinite dimension, $B$ to be finite dimensional, and $D$ to be of countably infinite dimension.

Comment: I think it is a good answer!. I have a question: is it false when we are talking about finite dimensional vector spaces? i.e. we can not find vector spaces such that they fulfill those constraints.

Comment: I would have to say that it's probably false in that case. This is only an intuition though, not a well thought out response.

Comment: @DiegoHuerfano You can show that it is false in the finite dimensional case by noting again that a vector space over a given field is determined up to isomorphism class by the cardinality of its dimension, and just doing arithmetic ($S \oplus B \cong S\oplus D \iff |B|=|D|$ by subtracting $|S|$ from both sides).